# Scatter plot multiclass labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I'm trying to implement `SMOTE` technic and thus I would like to visualize my labels. This technic helps me solve the data imbalance problem.

I have, say, 1000 labels of `1, 2, and 3` and the counts are `100, 100, 800` respectively. After `SMOTE`, I will add synthetic values so that I will have `800, 800, and 800` for `1, 2, and 3` labels.

Now I want to plot these labels before and after `SMOTE`. I have divided my dataset into `train_X` and `train_y`. I tried to adjust iris code to my dataset but I failed. This is what I tried (does not draw anything and giving `ValueError: 'c' argument has 154 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 25, 'y' with size 25.` error):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

features = train_X
target = train_y.values.ravel()

plt.scatter(features[0], features[1], alpha=0.2,
            s=100*features[3], c=target, cmap='viridis')
plt.xlabel("L1")
plt.ylabel("L2");
plt.show()
```

How can I plot my labels with different colors so that I can take a look how the values are distributed?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Bazingaa Ofc, but what's the problem with this question?

Comment: We cannot run this code. The error is clear that the size of x y and color parameter is different

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll be more careful. But I'm pretty sure my parameters have the same sizes. `features` has shape of `(154, 25)` and `target` has shape of`(154, )`

Comment: If python complains about it, then they cannot be same size. Try printing their shape in the line before the error generates

Comment: If `np.shape(features) == (154, 25)` then `features[0]` will have length 25....